# Where are good places to get gelato in Rome?

Tags: food-and-drink, recommendations, shopping, rome

In most cities, there are recommendable gelato shops. Rome is in Italy, so I guess every gelato is very good, but are there some shops in Rome where gelato is even a bit better then elsewhere? :-)

Comment: Sounds like a shopping recommendation, which is generally off-topic. Especially when it comes to food, I imagine, it's a very subjective matter. But then I don't know the gelato market. Can one be objectively better than another?

Comment: Where is the difference to "Must-see places in Goa?" for instance? Must-see is kind of subjective... Nevertheless, I think I will delete the question

Comment: "Must-see" is a bit subjective, and I might possibly raise an objection to such a question if I see it. On the other hand, it sounds more like a question of "what are the most popular places in Goa?" Which I may also object to on grounds of being a list question... OTOH, the Goa question can likely be answered with a link to a single tourism bureau (or similar) web site.

Comment: as it stands this question could have a hundred answers.  It's pretty subjective - each Roman probably has their own favourite place.  If you can rephrase it - like "what's the oldest gelato place" or "the closest to x" which can be objectively answered, then flag it for reopening, but as it stands it's not a good fit as per the [faq] and is being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you to try [Petrini](http://www.gelato.it/petrini/index2.htm)

Another very famous one (which is part of a well known brand in Italy) is [Grom](http://www.grom.it/eng/dettagli_gelateria.php?id_gelateria=234&citt%E0=Roma)